# UIAComWrapper API related Methods throwing Element Not Available Exception on Windows 10

Tags: automation

I am using UIAComWrapper.dll related methods in our code FindFirst(),FindALL() and GetParent().

Randomly each Method is throwing ElementNotAvailableException.

**Exceptions as follows:**

```
 System.Windows.Automation.ElementNotAvailableException was caught
  HResult=-2147220991
  Message=Element not available
  Source=UiaComWrapper 


   InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
    ErrorCode=-2146233083
   HResult=-2146233083
   Message=Operation timed out. 

  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131505)
    Source=Interop.UIAutomationClient

   StackTrace:
        at     UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationTreeWalker.GetParentElementBuildCache(IUIAutomationElement element, IUIAutomationCacheRequest cacheRequest)
        at System.Windows.Automation.TreeWalker.GetParent(AutomationElement element, CacheRequest request)"
```

Regards,

Nagasree.